# Docker node installation

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to prepare a docker image to speed-up the building process and to avoid installing various tools and libs every build, my base image will contain it and then I will use it with all installed things I need.

So the problem is that I'm trying to install node from NVM (Node Version Manager) but after I install I cannot use nor `nvm` nor `npm` command.

My base image is golang:1.13.1 and I do the following things.

`RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`

Then among tutorials, I saw that `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` must be run to finish the job like below

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"`

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm`

I changed it a little bit because my docker image does not recognize few commands due to different shells.

But when I do two separate `RUN`, the second one does not see `NVM_DIR` anymore. Of course, I can do everything in one `RUN` but I need to have `npm` later on, so each `RUN` should be able to see this command.

Also, I tried exporting `NVM_DIR` but it still does not work even when I restart with `. ~/.bashrc`.

The point of having NVM is that I don't want to care about the node version. Each build will be a LTS version and this is OK for me.

Sharing your solution or advice is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need `nvm` or a solution installing directly `node` will help you? And why not use `go-apline` image

Comment: nvm is better for me due to `nvm install --lts | nvm use --lts`. I installed node and npm with some other command but it's less convenient because version must be provided. The more automatic it is the better.

Comment: you do not need node version manager (NVM) to manage version in case of Docker, each docker image represents a single version then why bother to install `NVM` in Docker? go with `golang:1.13.1-alpine3.10` and then just install node `apk add --no-cache node` or specify any version which you want. this also install `lts`

Comment: @Adiii I use more things that I install with apt-get which golang image provides. But with alpine I have only apk, so it's not convenient for me to rewrite all my download things

Answer (score 0):

The way to install nodejs with npm without changing image and without nvm (which I don't really like) is

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After `RUN npm -v` and `RUN node -v` it's the same as nvm's LTS version so 6.9.0 and 10.16.3.

I couldn't find better solution but I hope it may help someone